# Как закрыть и потом снова открыть окно браузера?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

При попытке запуска следующего кода

```
drive = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_locator)
drive.get(any_syte)
drive.close()
drive.get(any_syte)
```

получаю ошибку WebDriverException: Message: no such session
Есть ли возможность закрыть и потом открыть новое окно в пределах одной вебсессии?

Comment: а это у вас единственное открытое окно? Просто если закрыть единственное окно, то браузер тоже закроется.

Comment: да окно единственное. Смысл в том и есть, чтобы переоткрыть закрытое окно.

Comment: а вы не можете просто его зарефрешить?

Comment: refresh() не помог, пробую рестартовать вебсессию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте после `close`, вызвать метод `drive.start_session({})`, так как при вызове метода `close` закрывается открытая сессия.

```
drive = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_locator)
drive.get(any_syte)
drive.close()
drive.start_session({})
drive.get(any_syte)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. работает

Comment: Настройки вы уже передали при создании объекта Chrome. При вызове start_session, вы просто создаете еще одну сессию с новым окном с теми же параметрами, для этого достаточно передать пустой словарь первым аргументом. Если вы хотите изменить некоторые настройки, то можно передать словарь с новыми значениями `desired_capabilities`.